# Not loading localhost page in docker using webdevops/php-apache-dev image

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, server

I need to setup a local docker server in windows 11, i using yml file which is partially working.
`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` running up command it running everything fine.
even `localhost:8080` page shows phpmyadmin page as per yml configuration.
But `local.domain.com` shows page not found and
`localhost` show Internal Server Error.
I need to direct local.domain.com or locahost to app folder of docker container.

i have tried yml shown below

```
version: '3'
services:
   web:
       image: webdevops/php-apache-dev:8.1
       container_name: web
       restart: always
       user: application
       environment:
         - WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=local.domain.com
         - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app
         - PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=EST
         - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
         - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
         - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
         - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
         - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=1024M
       volumes:
         - D:/docker/container/magento:/app:cached
       ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
         - "32823:22"
       links:
         - mysql
   mysql:
       image: mariadb:10.6
       container_name: mysql
       restart: always
       ports:
         - "3306:3306"
       environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
         - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento2.4.5
       volumes:
         - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
   phpmyadmin:
       container_name: phpmyadmin
       restart: always
       image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
       environment:
         - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
         - PMA_USER=root
         - PMA_PASSWORD=root
       ports:
         - "8080:80"
       links:
         - mysql:db
       depends_on:
         - mysql
   elasticsearch:
        container_name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.0
        environment:
          - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
          - node.name=elasticsearch
          - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
          - discovery.type=single-node
          - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
          - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
        volumes:
          - magento-es-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        ports:
          - 9200:9200
volumes:
   db-data:
       external: false
   magento-es-data:
        external: false
```